# How to Use Usercontrol more than once inside one Control

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls

I created WPF UserControl which enables to enter some information now I have Main entry form where I want to use tow instances of that UserControl When I add my YserControl as Resource and than try to use it as ContrntControl's Content exception is thrown informing that control is already a logical child. Can anyone provide with sollution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `x:Shared` attribute so that whenever something references the resource, a new instance is created instead of it being shared.

Thus you might have something like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <MyUserControl x:Key="MyControlKey" x:Shared="False" .... />
    ....
</Window.Resources>
```

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx
- http://www.wpfmentor.com/2009/01/how-to-ensure-new-instance-of-resource.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found out way to not throw exception but I want to know if this is right sollution

```
            <TaicoControl:WizardPage Title="Title1"
                                 BackButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 CancelButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 Description="Desctiption1"
                                 PageType="Interior">
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PersonEntryFormTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding Person}" />
        </TaicoControl:WizardPage>
        <TaicoControl:WizardPage Title="Title2"
                                 BackButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 CancelButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 Description="Description2"
                                 NextButtonVisibility="Collapsed"
                                 PageType="Interior">
            <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource PersonEntryFormTemplate}" DataContext="{Binding Person.ContactPerson}" />
        </TaicoControl:WizardPage>
```